# Connection to HM-10 BLE module

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Developing an application through Android Studio in order to utilize a HM-10 Bluetooth module to send one single number from app to the board. I am trying to modify the Android Studio Developer code available [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#java) . And whole code available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt). I am messing around with the UUID and Code but I cannot get the module to show up.

I have downloaded different implementations on BLE scanners and read on the source code. For an example the FastBLE application connects flawlessly to the HM-10, however dissecting the code is very difficult as this is the first time I've implemented Bluetooth LE. I also do not need have the functionality that this offers. Code for that is located here. https://github.com/Jasonchenlijian/FastBle

From BluetoothLeservice.java

```
    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

I have yet to mess with the attributes as I did not know how it would effect connectivity with the device. I'm assuming that since I don't even see the Module pop up

```
public class SampleGattAttributes {
    private static HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap();
    public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

    static {
        // Sample Services.
        attributes.put("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Heart Rate Service");
        attributes.put("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Device Information Service");
        // Sample Characteristics.
        attributes.put(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT, "Heart Rate Measurement");
        attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    }

    public static String lookup(String uuid, String defaultName) {
        String name = attributes.get(uuid);
        return name == null ? defaultName : name;
    }
```

Would like to see the HM-10 module show up during scan first off, and afterwards be able to send a single digit to Arduino. Currently off the base heart rate monitor from the Android Studio website, the HM-10 Module does not show up during scan.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it. The Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself.